# How to add custom marker in rotating image of 3D using three.js

Tags: javascript, animation, 3d, three.js

I am having 360 view of an object and object image is rotating in a canvas. Now I want to add custom markers to highlight certain points with description. If image is moving the marker should move and come again if the same position appears again? kindly suggest.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Now I want when I will click on any position of the rotating image one popup will appear where I can upload marker image and description which will rotate along with the 3d image. ie after rotating back to same canvas it will show.